# DatePicker Selected value is Not updated automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I had, created two datepicker sample(`"#datepiicker1","#datepicker2"`) in a same page.The value selected in `#datepicker1` is assigned to `minDate` value for `#datepicker2`. In output , when i click the date from `#datepicker1` is automatically assigned as a `minDate` value for `#datepicker2`.
but when i select the date in `#datepicker1` second time,the selected date is assigned to `minDate` property(find it by dev tools) but it is not updated to `#datepicker2` automatically. After i click anywhere on that page ,the `minDate` value is applied to `#datepicker2`.

my code block:

```
        $(function () {
            $('#datepicker1').datepicker({ width: '180px', change: "OnChange" });
            $('#datepicker2').datepicker({ width: '180px'});


        })

        function OnChange(args) {

            $("#dateTime1").datepicker({ minDate: args.value });

        }
```

How to to do this ?

Comment: Pls add fiddle for your query

Comment: Would be helpful to post a jsfiddle with the html markup. Also: Is the use of #dateTime1 and #datepicker1 on purpose or the root of the problem?

Comment: This isn't clear at all, and jQuery's datepicker **has no** `width` or `change` settings ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to create a date range picker combo, you may try the following jquery code:

```
$("#dateFrom").off("dp.change");
$("#dateFrom").on("dp.change", function(e) {
        $("#dateTo").data("DateTimePicker").setMinDate(e.date);
});

$("#dateTo").off("dp.change");
$("#dateTo").on("dp.change", function(e) {
        $("#dateFrom").data("DateTimePicker").setMaxDate(e.date);
});
```

JSFiddle would certainly be helpful in answering your exact query. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
  onSelect: function() {
    $('#datepicker1').val(this.value);
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
TextBox1
<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date" /><br>
Textbox2
<input type="text" id="datepicker1" name="date1" />
```